# Dataframe image with matplotlib cant use alpha in color

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib

I am trying to style a dataframe column using a custom gradient color scheme

```py
import dateframe_image as dfi

def color_gradient(val):
    if val > 0:
        return f'background-color: rgba(61, 153, 112, {min(val / 10, 1)})'
    if val < 0:
        return f'background-color: rgba(225, 65, 54, {min(abs(val) / 10, 1)})'

df = pd.DataFrame([{'value': 5.3}, {'value': 1.3}, {'value': -1.5}])
styled_df = df.style.applymap(color_gradient, subset=['value'])
dfi.export(styled_df, 'test.png', table_conversion='matplotlib')
```

I get an error when I add the alpha value, it works fine if I remove it

```
ValueError: Invalid RGBA argument: 'rgba(61, 153, 112, 0.94)'
```

Answer (score 0):

how about this ?

```
dfi.export(df.style.background_gradient(), 'test.png', table_conversion='matplotlib')
```

Comment: This works but it doesnt use the custom gradient function I have

Comment: oh sorry, how about `styled_df.export_png('test.png')` ?